# How to pass datas dynamicly to another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, model

I'm trying to create a Rails app on which people can read mangas through chapters. For this, I created 3 scaffolds: one for the mangas themselves, another for the chapters, and a last one for the pages. I nested the resources so it looks like the following:

```
  resources :mangas do
    resources :chapters do
      resources :pejis
    end
  end
```

However, I want to create a system that auto increments the `chapter_number` (a column in the Chapter class) each time someone adds a new chapter to the same manga.

So I created a function, `another_one`, to count how many chapters exist with the same manga_id (the column telling from witch manga the chapters are from (a manga has_many :chapters, a chapter belongs_to :manga).

After that, it simply adds 1 to what it found then saves the result inside `chapter_number`.

However, I have a problem: Since the manga_id can be dynamic whether I choose to add some chapters to a manga or another, I need to specify it inside my function, which looks like this:

**chapter.rb**

```
def another_one
  self.class.where(:manga_id => @manga).count + 1
end
```

With this parameter, it doesn't properly work even thought it doesn't return any error. But, if I add (i.e) 4 instead of `@manga`, it will work perfectly.

My question is: is there a way to pass dynamicly this kind of variable, since `find(params[:id]` doesn't work inside a model ? And if not, how can I make it work in another way ?

Here is my controller, just in case

```
  def create
    @manga = Manga.find(params[:manga_id])
    @chapter = Chapter.new(chapter_params)
    @chapter.manga = @manga
    @chapter.chapter_number = @chapter.plus_un

    if @chapter.save
      (params[:images] || []).each_with_index do |image, index|
        @chapter.pejis.create(image: image, scan_number: index + 1)
      end
      redirect_to manga_chapter_path(@manga, @chapter), notice: 'Chapter was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

Comment: where are you trying to call add_another?

Comment: where are you trying to call self.class.where(:manga_id => @manga.id).count + 1 ?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to mention it, I set this function inside the chapter model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@chapter.chapter_number = @manga.chapters.count + 1
```

Comment: You have no idea how stupid I feel right now. Damnit. Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted the model to be responsible for calculating it's own sequence number, you could use the accessor for the `belongs_to` relation.

```
before_create :set_chapter_number

def set_chapter_number
  self.chapter_number = self.manga.chapters.length + 1
end
```

Personally though I think that this approach is inflexible ... what if you implemented the ability to insert a new chapter, delete a chapter, or reorganise chapters. In this case you might find the [act as list](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem would be a better approach.

Comment: I tried your answer yesterday, but it didn't work well for an unknown reason.. However, it appears that I was looking for exactly the gem you linked me, so you deserve an upvote ! :)